# How to update CAGradientlayer size after animation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created an extension class for UIText to create a gradient layer. After animating the UIText size the gradient layer size gets smaller than the UIText itsef that is the parent element. Here's my code:

```
extension UITextField {
func gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor){
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = super.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)  
}

class gradientTeLabel: UITextField {
    var once = true
    override func layoutSubviews() {  
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if once {
            self.gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor(red: 0.30, green: 0.55, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.36, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1))
            once = false
        }
    }
```

}

---------these were are in separate file--------

```
  @IBAction func showMarkUp(_ sender: Any) {
        if mark1.isHidden {
            _ = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.25, curve: .easeInOut){

            self.expandButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
            self.asdf.layer.frame = self.asdf.bounds
                }.startAnimation()
            asdf.layer.frame = asdf.bounds
        } else {
            _ = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.250, curve: .easeInOut){

            self.mark1.isHidden = true
                         }.startAnimation()
        }
    }
```

---------these are in ViewController--------

asdf is the UITextField that contains the gradient layer. How can I update the gradient layer size to match the UIText size?

Comment: override layoutsubviews and set the gradient's frame to the text bounds.

Comment: @Brandon it says 'override' can only be specified on class members, whether I type the code inside the animation closure or the class extension. What now?

Comment: So in the animation closure, set the frame of the gradient to the bounds of the text and also do it in the completion.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Added a few lines of code in the question for more insight into the problem.

Comment: @Brandon i checked frame & bounds and they are equal. However the gradient height is not equal to text height in reality. Is there any other way to match them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main choices.

- If possible, do not add "loose" sublayers like this. Instead, add a subview, with layout based on the superview (e.g. autoresizing or autolayout), so that when you perform view animation on the superview, the subview comes along for the ride.
- If you can't do that, then when you do view animation on the view, you must also do layer animation on the layer (using Core Animation) to match it.

Comment: The problem is, taking into account your second advice, autoLayout Engine takes care of the view heightAncor, so I kind of need to update somehow the layer to, But I dunno how.

Comment: I appreciate that fact, but that is what you will have to _learn_ to do if you want to animate a view that has a "loose" sublayer.