# How to convert heightAncor to CGFloat Type?

Tags: swift, nslayoutanchor

After changing the height of a UITextField using an animation, the Gradient Layer's height that is a subview doesn't match the parent height anynore.

I want to convert `heightAncor` of a view which is of type `NSLayoutDimensons` to `CGFloat`, so I can set the GradientLayer's `frame.size.height` equal to UITextField's `heightAncor` Is that even possible?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @matt check edit, please..

Comment: Don't think its possible but as per doc `A layout anchor representing the height of the view’s frame.` So you can directly get height by `view.frame.size.height`

Comment: @DharmeshKheni it doesn't really help me that much, 'cause the frame in my scenario gets slightly smaller in height that the parent element. So I need to see what is the difference between the two and match it somehow.

Comment: Okay, so this is a followup to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502631/how-to-update-cagradientlayer-size-after-animation. The problem is that you keep asking x-y questions, i.e. you're still not asking the question to which you need to know the answer. You are _assuming_ a way to solve the problem and asking about _that_, but you keep leading yourself down the wrong path.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, but in my case it is for screen rotations. I create a container view based on the frame size of the view in the portrait orientation. I need to, instead, find the CGFloat value of the anchors. It might not work anyways since the container size will still end up being set using the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so I can set the GradientLayer's frame.size.height equal to UITextField's heightAncor Is that even possible?

You don't need to read any values from the anchor, and it wouldn't do any good if you could. Constraints are merely instructions to the autolayout engine. You are not the engine, so constraints have little or no direct meaning to you.

If you put your code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, the autolayout engine will have done its work, and now you can get the text field's `frame.size.height` or `bounds.size.height` directly (or *any* view's frame or bounds), and it will be correct.

Comment: Oh, it's perfectly right, and answers the question you asked here. But it isn't going to get you the simultaneous animation of the text field and the gradient layer that you are actually after. You keep dancing around that without actually learning or asking about it.

Comment: I don't even know if what am I asking is what I need to ask. I just need to learn how to match the layer size to its superview after animating some changes. My project is fairly complex, above my knowledge and skills set, and I am doing my best to learn what I need to and can. Be sure I am doing all kind of research I can. Even read a bit on CALayers in your book(on https://www.safaribooksonline.com) but I am not sure I completely understood how to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm totally with you here, but I still think it would be useful to be clear on how to ask an effective question on Stack Overflow, and that's what I'm focusing on. You have still not said clearly what you're trying to do. Why would a text field even _have_ a gradient layer covering it? The user wouldn't be able to type any text if you did that. So it's hard to envision what the problem really is. By asking about the _actual effect_ you are trying to achieve, rather than assuming a partial solution in advance, you could get much better help. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: You're right! The Gradient Layer is added within an extension UITextField using layer.addSubLayer() method in a function constructor. And then I am applying a class on the UITextField, that creates the gradient by overrideing layoutSubviews()

Comment: I'm not asking what you're doing. I'm asking what you _want_ to do.

Comment: I have a view that extends and shows extra content. While showing it, it also hides some views. I am using StackViews all over the place so it auto-resizes for any device. Somehow, when the section extends, views are lesser in height than before, and the effect is that gradient layer is smaller than the view that updates its size correctly.

Comment: And _none_ of that is in _any_ question you've asked. That's why you keep spinning your wheels here. Make a new project, abstracting the problem so that it alone is replicated, and describe or post that project as you ask a new question!

Comment: Got it mate! Will do.